# Write multi-line secret to windows runner in GitHub workflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, github, github-actions

### Summary

What specific syntax must be changed in the code below in order for the multi-line contents of the `$MY_SECRETS` environment variable to be 1.) successfully written into the `C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml` file on a Windows runner in the GitHub workflow whose code is given below, and 2.) read by the simple Python 3 `main.py` program given below?

**PROBLEM DEFINITION:**

The `echo "$MY_SECRETS" > C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml` command is only printing the string literal `MY_SECRETS` into the `C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml` file instead of printing the multi-line contents of the `MY_SECRETS` variable.

We confirmed that this same `echo` command *does* successfully print the same multi-line secret in an ubuntu-latest runner, and we manually validated the correct contents of the `secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS` environment variable.  ...  This problem seems entirely isolated to either the windows command syntax, or perhaps to the windows configuration of the GitHub `windows-latest` runner, either of which should be fixable by changing the workflow code below.

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

The multi-line secret should be printed into the  `C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml` file and read by `main.py`.

The resulting printout of the contents of the `C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml` file should look like:

```
***  
***  
***  
***
```

**LOGS THAT DEMONSTRATE THE FAILURE:**

The result of running `main.py` in the GitHub Actions log is:

```
ccc item is:  $MY_SECRETS
```

As you can see, the string literal `$MY_SECRETS` is being wrongly printed out instead of the 4 `***` secret lines.

**REPO FILE STRUCTURE:**

Reproducing this error requires only 2 files in a repo file structure as follows:

```
.github/
    workflows/
        test.yml
main.py
```

**WORKFLOW CODE:**

The minimal code for the workflow to reproduce this problem is as follows:

```
name: write-secrets-to-file
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
jobs:
  write-the-secrets-windows:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: python
        name: Configure agent
        env:
          MY_SECRETS: ${{ secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS }}
        run: |
          import subprocess
          import pathlib
          pathlib.Path("C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
          print('About to: echo "$MY_SECRETS" > C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml')
          output = subprocess.getoutput('echo "$MY_SECRETS" > C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml')
          print(output)
          os.chdir('D:\\a\\myRepoName\\')
          mycmd = "python myRepoName\\main.py"
          p = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
          while(True):
            # returns None while subprocess is running
            retcode = p.poll() 
            line = p.stdout.readline()
            print(line)
            if retcode is not None:
              break
```

**MINIMAL APP CODE:**

Then the minimal `main.py` program that demonstrates what was actually written into the `C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml` file is:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml') as file:
  for item in file:
    print('ccc item is: ', str(item))
    if "var1" in item:
      print("Found var1")
```

**STRUCTURE OF MULTI-LINE SECRET:**

The structure of the multi-line secret contained in the `secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS` environment variable is:

```
var1:value1
var2:value2
var3:value3
var4:value4
```

These 4 lines should be what gets printed out when `main.py` is run by the workflow, though the print for each line should look like `***` because each line is a secret.

Comment: I'm investigating why this `output = subprocess.getoutput('echo "$MY_SECRETS" > C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml')` isn't working but I think doing `MY_SECRETS=os.getenv("MY_SECRETS")` and then doing  `output =subprocess.getoutput('echo "{}" > C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml').format(MYSECRETS)` will work

Comment: You should narrow down the problem and write a minimal test code. This is not useful(You didn't even specify the python version).

Comment: @relent95 Two other users were able to meet the requirements specified by this OP.  Also, this OP has had a python3 tag from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: updated with fixed `main.py` and how to run it.

You can write the key file directly with Python:

```py
      - shell: python
        name: Configure agent
        env:
          MY_SECRETS: ${{ secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS }}
        run: |
          import os
          import pathlib
          pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
          with open('C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml', 'w') as key_file:
            key_file.write(os.environ['MY_SECRETS'])
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Run main
        run: python main.py
```

To avoid newline characters in your output, you need a `main.py` that removes the newlines (here with `.strip().splitlines()`):

`main.py`

```py
with open('C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml') as file:
    for item in file.read().strip().splitlines():
        print('ccc item is: ', str(item))
        if "var1" in item:
            print("Found var1")
```

Here's the input:

```
LIST_OF_SECRETS = '
key:value
key2:value
key3:value
'
```

And the output:

```
ccc item is:  ***
Found var1
ccc item is:  ***
ccc item is:  ***
ccc item is:  ***
```

Here is my complete workflow:

```py
name: write-secrets-to-file
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  write-the-secrets-windows:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - shell: python
        name: Configure agent
        env:
          MY_SECRETS: ${{ secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS }}
        run: |
          import os
          import pathlib
          pathlib.Path('C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
          with open('C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml', 'w') as key_file:
            key_file.write(os.environ['MY_SECRETS'])
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Run main
        run: python main.py
```

Also, a simpler version using only Windows shell (Powershell):

```yaml
      - name: Create key file
        env:
          MY_SECRETS: ${{ secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS }}
        run: |
          mkdir C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir
          echo "$env:MY_SECRETS" > C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Run main
        run: python main.py
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is - as it is so often - the quirks of Python with byte arrays and strings and en- and de-coding them in the right places...

Here is what I used:

### test.yml:

```
name: write-secrets-to-file
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - dev
jobs:
  write-the-secrets-windows:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: python
        name: Configure agent
        env:
          MY_SECRETS: ${{ secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS }}
        run: |
          import subprocess
          import pathlib
          import os
          # using os.path.expanduser() instead of hard-coding the user's home directory
          pathlib.Path(os.path.expanduser("~/somedir")).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
          secrets = os.getenv("MY_SECRETS")
          with open(os.path.expanduser("~/somedir/mykeys.yaml"),"w",encoding="UTF-8") as file:
              file.write(secrets)
          mycmd = ["python","./main.py"]
          p = subprocess.Popen(mycmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
          while(True):
              # returns None while subprocess is running
              retcode = p.poll()
              line = p.stdout.readline()
              # If len(line)==0 we are at EOF and do not need to print this line.
              # An empty line from main.py would be '\n' with len('\n')==1!
              if len(line)>0:
                # We decode the byte array to a string and strip the
                # new-line characters \r and \n from the end of the line,
                # which were read from stdout of main.py
                print(line.decode('UTF-8').rstrip('\r\n'))
              if retcode is not None:
                  break
```

### main.py:

```
import os
# using os.path.expanduser instead of hard-coding user home directory
with open(os.path.expanduser('~/somedir/mykeys.yaml'),encoding='UTF-8') as file:
    for item in file:
        # strip the new-line characters \r and \n from the end of the line
        item=item.rstrip('\r\n')
        print('ccc item is: ', str(item))
        if "var1" in item:
            print("Found var1")
```

### secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS:

```
var1: secret1
var2: secret2
var3: secret3
var4: secret4
```

And my output in the log was

```
ccc item is:  ***
Found var1
ccc item is:  ***
ccc item is:  ***
ccc item is:  ***
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code and it worked fine :

LIST_OF_SECRETS

```
key1:val1
key2:val2
```

Github action (test.yml)

```
name: write-secrets-to-file
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  write-the-secrets-windows:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: python
        name: Configure agentt
        env:
          MY_SECRETS: ${{ secrets.LIST_OF_SECRETS }}
        run: |
          import base64, subprocess, sys
          import os
          secrets = os.environ["MY_SECRETS"]
          
          def powershell(cmd, input=None):
              cmd64 = base64.encodebytes(cmd.encode('utf-16-le')).decode('ascii').strip()
              stdin = None if input is None else subprocess.PIPE
              process = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "-NonInteractive", "-EncodedCommand", cmd64], stdin=stdin, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
              if input is not None:
                  input = input.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
              output, stderr = process.communicate(input)
              output = output.decode(sys.stdout.encoding).replace('\r\n', '\n')
              return output
          
          command = r"""$secrets = @'
          {}
          '@
          $secrets | Out-File -FilePath .\mykeys.yaml""".format(secrets)
          
          command1 = r"""Get-Content -Path .\mykeys.yaml"""
          
          powershell(command)
          print(powershell(command1))
```

Output

```
***
***
```

As you also mention in the question, Github will obfuscate any printed value containing the secrets with `***`

EDIT : Updated the code to work with multiple line secrets. This answer was highly influenced by [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27012999/6126446)

Comment: Okay, this doesn't work with multiple line secrets. Seems like a powershell issue fixing it now.

Comment: @CodeMed I updated the answer to work for multiple lines. Yes it may sound a bit weird having to encode the powershell commands into base64 before executing them, but this solved all the formatting/encoding issues between Python and Powershell that I encondered trying to use powershell's here string. As to why we are stating powershell in the command, we have to because we are overriding Action's default shell with Python and then the shell it opens is cmd.

Comment: Your code does not call `main.py` as specified in the OP.  Your code breaks when we use it to call `main.py`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `yaml` library:

```
import yaml

data = {'MY_SECRETS':'''
var1:value1
var2:value2
var3:value3
var4:value4
'''}#add your secret 

with open('file.yaml', 'w') as outfile: # Your file
    yaml.dump(data, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

This is result:
[image: Result]
[I used this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470665/how-can-i-write-data-in-yaml-format-in-a-file)

Comment: This works only if you have access to `C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\somedir\\mykeys.yaml`.

Comment: Can you please test your code on an actual GitHub workflow calling a runner with `windows-latest` as the OP specifies?  Your code does not work in the environment specified in the OP.  It only takes a few minutes to set up the minimal example from the OP in a new GitHub repository if you have a free GitHub account.